# Indefinite integral of $\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 +2x +2}{(x^2 +2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x - 2)}$

Tags: integration

How do I find $$\int\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 +2x +2}{(x^2 +2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x - 2)}\mathrm dx$$

I used partial fractions by breaking up $x^2 + 2x - 2$ into $(x+1)^2 - 3$ and split it into $(a+b)(a-b)$ but as u can see it's extreme tedious. I was wondering if there is a faster technique to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 +2x +2}{(x^2 +2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x - 2)}\mathrm dx\\
=\int\left(+\frac{2x+2}{2(x^2+2x+2)}+\frac{2x+2}{2(x^2+2x-2)}-\frac1{\frac{(2x+2)^2}4+1}\right)\mathrm dx\\
=\frac12\ln(x^2+2x+2)+\frac12\ln(x^2+2x-2)-\arctan\left(\frac{2x+2}2\right)+\mathbb C$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Write $$\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 +2x +2)}{(x^2 +2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x - 2)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2x+2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+2x-2}$$

For the ease of calculation, we can write

$$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac A2\cdot\frac{\left(\dfrac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{dx}\right)}{x^2+2x+2}+\frac C{(x+1)^2+1^2}.$$

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I'll try that now

Comment: @DannyLim, Please find the edited version

Comment: How did you get that??

Comment: @DannyLim. Obviously, you do not know lab !

Comment: @DannyLim, Where is your confusion?